# How do I dynamically set the type of PowerShell variables?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get a System.Type from a string and then apply it to a variable?

The following is the function that I tried to convert to make it safer (i.e. not involve invoking a string):

```
Function ParseLine($Type, $VariableName, $Value){
    Invoke-Expression "[$Type] `$$VariableName = $Value"
}
```

I looked at `New-Variable` and `Set-Variable`, but there is no type-setting-related parameter in the definition.

I expected something that looks like below, but I couldn't find the parameter `Type` or equivalent:

```
Function ParseLine($Type, $VariableName, $Value){
    New-Variable -Name $VariableName -Value $Value -Type ([type] $Type)
}
```

**Context:** I am experimenting to create a simple parser definition that looks like:

```
$ResponseLogFormat = New-InputFormat {
    ParseLine -Type int -VariableName RecordLength
    RepeatedSection -RepeatCount $RecordLength {
        ParseLine string +ComputerName
        ParseLine double +AverageResponse
    }
}

$ResponseLogFormat.Parse( $FilePath )
```

Comment: Instead of trying to set the variable type, perhaps you should consider ensuring the data is the type you want? For example, you could ensure your ParseLine function takes a converter function instead of a string, so that for double it would be `ParseLine [Convert]::ToDouble +ComputerName`. This would allow your function to support parsing custom types as well, by passing in a scriptblock which returns the new property value. You could support some default converters as well, which it could lookup based on a name, if you want to. Let me know if you want me to write an answer with a sample.

Comment: Do you mean `ParseLine {[Convert]::ToDouble} +ComputerName`? As for now, I am using function definition like `ParseLine($Type,$VariableName,$ParseScript)` with 'anytype' mapped to * so that I can do the following for custom object: `ParseLine * Response {New-CustomObject $CurrentLine}`. But it would be interesting to see the converter approach instead :)

Comment: If you give me a few sample lines to parse (and the expected output for the sample lines), I'll write up a sample which parses those lines. Please edit the question to add the additional information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can cast variables to a specific type using the `-as` operator:

```
Function ParseLine($Type, $VariableName, $Value){
    Set-Variable $VariableName -Scope 1 -Value ($Value -as ($Type -as [type]))
}
```

That will use `-as` to create a type from the `$Type` string, and then use that to cast `$Value`.

I am not sure of your intent with the variable, but if you want to persist it after the function is finished, you need to set it in the parent scope.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Based on your answer, I use the following line : `Set-Variable $VariableName -Scope script -Value ($Value -as ([type] $Type))`.