# How to write a PowerShell CmdLet that will accept a parameter of type System.Type?

Tags: powershell, types, parameters, parameter-passing, powershell-cmdlet

I want to pass a `Type` to a custom CmdLet, as follows:

```
PS> "1" | My-CmdLet -Check [System.String]
```

I want to use the `-Check` parameter as the type argument for the `-Is` operator in my CmdLet:

```
Function My-CmdLet {
    param(
        ${Actual},

        [System.String]
        ${Check}           # <-- I want to pass a type here
    )

    if (-not ($Actual -Is [Type] $Check)) {
        # ... 
    }
}
```

When called as follows:

```
PS> My-CmdLet 1 -Check [System.String]
```

Results in the error:

```
Cannot convert the "[System.String]" value of type "System.String" to type  "System.Type". At MycmdLet.ps1:19 char:9
 +     if (-not ($Actual -Is [Type] $ExpectedType)) {
 +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToType
```

I tried using `[System.String]`, `[System.Type]` `[System.Object]`, `[System.RunTimeType]` as the type for the `Check` parameter, but none of those seem to be working.

For comparison:

I can pass a type to the Where-Object cmdlet like this:

```
PS> Get-Process | Where-Object StartTime -Is [System.Datetime]
```

(In this case the value "[System.DateTime]" gets passed on to the CmdLet parameter `$Value` which is of type `[System.Object]`)

I can use a Type with the `-Is` operator like this:

```
PS> "1" -Is [System.String]
True
```

**How do i declare the `-Check` parameter in my CmdLet?**

Comment: You might check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042428/how-to-dynamically-set-type-of-powershell-variable

Comment: You should pass it as `System.String` or `([System.String])`.

Comment: `if($Check.StartsWith('[') -and $Check.EndsWith(']')){$Check = $Check.Substring(1, $Check.Length-2)}`

Comment: The reason `"1" -is [System.String]` works is because the type-operators (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847763.aspx) is designed to expect the square-brackets expression. A parameter value however, is not.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you wouldn't just declare the parameter of type `System.Type` in the first place?

```
function Get-FullyQualifiedTypeName
{
    param([System.Type]$Type)

    Write-Host $Type.FullName
}
```

If you pass an actual `Type`, it will be accepted, otherwise, the parser will try to resolve your (partial) typename string to an actual `[type]` for you. No need to re-implement something that the parser already does for you!

```
PS> Get-FullyQualifiedTypeName $([psobject])
System.Management.Automation.PSObject
PS> Get-FullyQualifiedTypeName string
System.String
```

So in your case, you'd do something like

```
function Check-Type
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeLine)]
        [psobject]$Actual,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Type]$Check
    )

    $Actual -is $Check
}
```

Should get you what you want:

```
PS> "1" |Check-Type -Check string
True
PS> "1" |Check-Type -Check int
False
PS> 1 |Check-Type -Check int
True
```

Comment: This still fails when you cal it with `"1" | Check-Type -Check [System.String]`

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Well, that's simply how the parser works. If you want to pass a type literal as an argument you have to put it in a sub-expression or a variable to avoid the whole thing being interpreted as a string. Why is it so important to defy this behavior?

Comment: I don't wan't to 'defy' this behavior, I want my sybntax to be consistent with other cmdLets and parameters that take a `[Type]` parameter (for example `Where-Object -Is [Type]`)

Comment: In that case, @PetSerAl is spot on with his comment, you need to accept a string, and then remove outermost `[]` (if present) inside the function before casting (this is exactly what `Where-Object` does internally)

Answer (score 1):

`[System.String]` (notice the square brackets) is an expression and because of that it can't be as a parameter value without being wrapped in a grouping expression `()` or a subexpression `$()`. It is simply a PowerShell shortcut for something like `[type]::GetType("System.String")` (`typeof()` in c#).

`System.String` however is a string which PowerShell's automatic type conversion will successfully convert to a `Type`-object.

```
function Test-Type
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeLine=$true)]
        [PSObject]$Object,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Type]$Type
    )

    $Object -is $Type
}

Test-Type "c" -Type ([string])
1 | Test-Type -Type string
1 | Test-Type -Type ([int])
"1" | Test-Type -Type string

#Output
True
False
True
True
```

As an alternative, you can use a string-parameter and convert it to `Type`-object yourself inside your function. This way you can remove the square-brackets yourself to make the type conversion work. Like this:

```
function Test-Type
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeLine=$true)]
        [PSObject]$Object,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Type
    )

    #Remove square brackets and convert to type-object
    $Type = [System.Type]($Type -replace '^\[(.*)\]$', '$1')

    $Object -is $Type
}

Test-Type "c" -Type [string]
1 | Test-Type -Type string
1 | Test-Type -Type [int]
"1" | Test-Type -Type string

#Output
True
False
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the parameter as string and cast it via [type].

For example:

```
$a=1
$b="System.Int32"
$a -is [type]$b
```

This should return $true.

Comment: Using that is a CmdLet results in `Cannot convert the "[System.String]" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".`

Comment: Which Powershell Version are you using? -  Because in my case it doesn't matter if I pass in `"System.Int32"` or `[System.Int32]` - in both cases the target type is compared. I'm using Powershell 5.

Comment: v5. The code in your example does work when you execute it directly, but not when you make it a cmdlet with a string parameter and try calling it with `[System.Int32]`..

Comment: I get your point... I just have a workaround for you:
`$Actual -is [type]$Check.Replace("[","").Replace("]","")` - where $Check is defined as [psobject]

Comment: I went with that idea as well (removing the square brackets from the string), but it feels a bit .. unnatural. I'm hoping there is a better answer out there ..

Comment: I started looking around in the code for `Where-Object` with ILSpy; the code is a maze of abstraction. It does seem to just parse values to convert the value to a `Type` instance. So perhaps taking in a string and parsing a bit is not really that bad ..